# Kotlin: Force inline method to preserve the amount of defined lines

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, inline

So I have this method that I want to use for logging while also returning the logged object:

```
inline fun <T> T.btwLog(prefix:String="")=apply { Timber.d("$prefix->${toString()}") }
```

The Timber class is from a logging Library and also (when set up this way) shows the line at which it was called, which is also why the method is inline (to show the line and correct class of where it was called)
For example:

```
val b = someThingComplex().btwLog()
```

This basically works, the only problem is that the line number is wrong. This basically has to be because Kotlin inserts the method and while doing so adds some lines to the class (4)?.

So the example from before probably looks similar to this:

```
val b = someThingComplex()
        .apply { 
        Timber.d("$prefix->${toString()}")
        }
```

An alternative is this method where Kotlin doesn't add additional lines:

```
inline fun Any.log(s:String="")= Timber.d(s+this)
```

Is there any way that I could force Kotlin to just inline it exactly as I wrote it and not add linebreaks and stuff? Or is there a better way that I could define the method in general?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the shifting of line numbers might be due to the call to `apply`. Try it this way.

```
inline fun <T> T.btwLog(prefix: String = ""): T {
    Timber.d(prefix + "->" + this)
    return this
}
```